# Object of class Closure could not be converted into a string

Tags: php, closures

Alright so I am trying to use basic closures but it seems I am doing something wrong, I am constantly getting this error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted
>   to string in

and this is the code

```
<?php

    $var1 = 1;
    $var2 = 2;
    $var3 = rand(1,2);


    $calc = function() use ($var1, $var2, $var3) {
        if($var1>=$var2) $total = $var1-$var2;
        else $total = ($var2-$var1)/$var3;
        return $total;
    };

    echo $calc;
?>
```

Comment: `echo $calc();` Notice the braces. Closures are like functions. Technically they're functions - functions without names. Anonymous functions.

Comment: Ahhhhh thanks a lot mate!